# using 1 WITH statement with multiple (n) INSERTs

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.5

I wanted to know if it is possible to create one WITH statement and add multiple data values to other table with select, or do any equivalent thing.

I have 2 tables

1. **one has data**

```
create table bg_item(
    item_id text primary key default 'a'||nextval('bg_item_seq'),
    sellerid bigint not null references bg_user(userid),
    item_type char(1)not null default 'N', --NORMAL (public)
    item_upload_date date NOT NULL default current_date,
    item_name varchar(30) not null,
    item_desc text not null,
```

2. **other has images link**

```
create table item_images(
    img_id bigint primary key default nextval('bg_item_image_seq'),
    item_id text not null references bg_item (item_id),
    image_link text not null
);
```

The user can add item to sell and upload images of it, now these images can be 3 or more, now when i will add the images, and complete item's description and everything from app, my request goes to backend, and i want to perform the query that it adds the user's item, sends me the item's id (which is a sequence in PostgresSQL) and use that id to reference images that i am inserting.

Currently i was doing this (for 1 image):

```
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO bg_item(sellerid,item_type,item_date,item_name,item_desc,item_specs,item_category)
   VALUES (1005, 'k',default,'asdf','asdf','asd','asd')
   RETURNING item_id
   )
   INSERT INTO item_images (item_id, image_link) 
   select item_id,'asdfg.asd.asdf.com' from ins1
```

(for 3 images)

```
   INSERT INTO bg_item(sellerid,item_type,item_date,item_name,item_desc,item_specs,item_category)
   VALUES (1005, 'k',default,'asdf','asdf','asd','asd')
   RETURNING item_id
   )
   INSERT INTO item_images (item_id, image_link) 
   select item_id,'asdfg.asd.asdf.com' from ins1
select item_id,'asdfg.asdaws3f.com' from ins1
select item_id,'asdfg.gooolefnsd.sfsjf.com' from ins1
```

This would work for 3 images.

So my question is how to do it with n number of images? (as user can upload from 1 to n images)

Can i write a for loop?
a procedure or function?

References:

[With and Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20561627)

[Sql multiple insert select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11340470/14267431)

I didn't understand the Edit 3 (if it is related to my answer) in the above one.

One Solution i can think of is to write a procedure to return me item_id and write one more procedure to run multiple inserts, but i want a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to work with SQL then there is a concept you need to expel from your thoughts -- LOOP. As soon as you think it, it is time to rethink. It does not exist is SQL and is not typically needed. SQL works in `sets of qualifying things` not individual things.  
Now to your issue, it can be done is 1 statement. You *pass* your image list as an array of text in the `with` clause, then [unnest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-array.html) that array and join to your existing cte during the Insert/Select:

```
with images (ilist) as 
     ( 
      select array['image1','image2','image3','image4','image5']
     )
   , item (item_id) as
     ( 
       insert into bg_item(sellerid,item_type,item_date,item_name,item_desc,item_specs,item_category)
            values (1005, 'k',default,'asdf','asdf','asd','asd')
         returning item_id
     )
   insert into item_images (item_id, image_link) 
      select item_id,unnest (ilist) 
        from images
        join item on true;
```

Comment: Even easier than unnesting an array (unless you use parameterised queries, admittedly): `VALUES`.

Comment: @Bergi. Yes, but I do tend toward parameterized queries.